# What is the equivalent data type for byte in iOS swift?

Tags: java, swift

In Java we have data type called `byte` but in Swift there is no `byte` data type available.

In the example below I typecasted the ASCII (0xAF = 175) value by using `byte` data type.

```
byte abyte = (byte) 0xAF;
```

And the result is `abyte= -89`

How do I acheive this in Swift?

Comment: From the reference https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID317: *"Swift provides signed and unsigned integers in 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit forms."*

Comment: Google ‘byte type swift’ answer are all over the place

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The data type is Unsigned Int 8 (UInt8).

```
var byte:UInt8 = 0xAF
```

For a string of bytes:

```
var bytes:[UInt8] = [0xAF,0xAB]
```

For the bytes from data:

```
var data = Data()
var bytes = data.bytes //[UInt8]
```

Comment: Also, you actually don't need to convert the `Data` to an `Array<UInt8>` (which would be done using `Array(data)` instead of `data.bytes`), because `Data` conforms to `Sequence` and has an element type of `UInt8`, so it basically behaves similar to an array, so you can iterate over it, access its elements using a subscript (`data[42]`) etc.

Answer (score 5):

Swift bytes is [UInt8], UInt8 is 0 ... 255, Int8 is -128 ~ 127, you can get the Int8 value which like java byte with follow code.

```
extension UInt8 {
    var int8: Int8 {
        return Int8(self > 127 ? Int(self) - 256 : Int(self))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin use **byteArray.toUByteArray()** to convert to UInt8